# C++ Calling a derived class function from the base class

Tags: c++, derived-class

I'm not sure how to call a derived class function from the base class without getting some sort of error, here's a skeleton of the code I'm trying to work with...

```
class DiceGame{
public:
    virtual void play(){
        // Trying to call the derived class
        // Knockout's play function in here
        // I've been trying this

        DiceGame *game = new Knockout;
        game->play();

        // But it gives me a memory error
    }

class Knockout : public DiceGame{
    void play(){
        // This has the stuff I want to call
    }

main(){
    DiceGame *game = new DiceGame();
    game->play();
}
```

I have tried forward declaration of the Knockout class, but that gives me an incomplete forward declaration error as well, any advice?

Comment: Generally speaking a BaseClass should not know about it's derived classes.

Comment: My suggestion would be to make `virtual void play_internal()` and derive that, and you would call that inside `play()` (which would no longer be virtual)

Comment: @Borgleader Not related to the question, but purely curiosity: in which case(s) should a BaseClass now about it's derived classes?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `DiceGame *game = new Knockout();` and get rid of DiceGame::play content.

Comment: You are trying to call, from a virtual member function, the overridden implementation for that very same function on a new locally dynamically allocated instance specific derived type. This is all very suspicious to me and likely not the solution to your problem.

Comment: @DrIvol I cant think of a case, but "never say never", hence "Generally speaking"

Comment: `main` returns `int`. Beware of using `new` where it isn't necessary. This is not Java or C#. In any case, if you really need dynamic allocation, you should consider using smart pointers instead of owning raw pointers. For example `auto game = std::make_unique<DiceGame>();`.

Comment: 1) You don't call the **overridden** function in the base class _directly_. 2) Your `main` function shouldn't be creating the (often abstract) base class; create the subclass of `DiceGame` that you want to play. (_Note type hierarchy means that `DiceGame *game = new SUBCLASS...` is valid_) 3) Then when you call `game->play()`, the subclass's implementation will be called automatically.

Comment: @DrIvol @Borgleader Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) will access the derived members directly from the base, but then it knows exactly what the derived type is (you do like `class Derived : public Base<Derived>`) Only case I know of though.

Comment: Why not just 'play()' given it's virtual?

Comment: @Steve While not immediately wrong, you might want to offer a little more explanation. E.g. Calling `play()` from within `DiceGame::play()` would lead to an unpleasant outcome. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
class DiceGame{
public:
    virtual void play() = 0;
};

class Knockout : public DiceGame{
public:
    virtual void play() { // Replace "virtual" with "override" here if your compiler supports "override" keyword.
        // This has the stuff I want to call
    }
};

int main()
{
    DiceGame *game = new Knockout();
    game->play();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest one improvement: In the `Knockout` subclass, use the `override` 
specifier instead of `virtual`. This feature is available as of C++11.

Comment: @CraigYoung, you are right but I intentionally have not used `override` for this is beginner question.

Comment: I believe teaching `override` is better for beginners: 1) The specifier names align better with the polymorphism concepts. 2) It avoids the trivial error case where override isn't called because the signature is slightly different.

Comment: @CraigYoung, I have added note about "override".